# Using docker image of maven with jenkins - could not create local repository

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins

I am fairly new to Jenkins and Docker, and I am hitting a problem trying to get a docker image of maven to build my project.

My Jenkins script is fairly straightforward atm:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
        image 'maven:3-alpine'
        args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean install'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This produces the error "Could not create local repository at /var/empty/.m2/repository".  If I specify a local repo in the command line I get the same error for whatever path I specified.

Jenkins is installed and running on a tomcat server, not in docker, which Jenkins mentions each time it runs, saying "Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container".

The Jenkins console output looks like this:

```
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 123:128 -v /root/.m2:/root/.m2 -w /usr/share/tomcat7/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject -v /usr/share/tomcat7/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject:/usr/share/tomcat7/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject:rw,z -v /usr/share/tomcat7/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject@tmp:/usr/share/tomcat7/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** maven:3-alpine cat
$ docker top 70c607bda0e397ed8ff79a183f33b2953ed94d82e4f36eb26dea87fa8c67adf3 -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] sh
[OMRS] Running shell script
+ mvn -B -DskipTests clean install
[ERROR] Could not create local repository at /var/empty/.m2/repository -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of mounting the root/.m2 folder to the container, you probably just need to run as root user:

```
pipeline {


agent {
    docker {
        image 'maven:3-alpine'
        args '-u root'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean install'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this has worked, but now I am getting a different error from Maven within Docker, saying it "Name or service not known: Unknown host mvn".  I'm going to create a new question for that.  Thanks.

Comment: You probably named the agent host 'mvn' even that you don't have such agent

Comment: Close - actually I had stupidly forgot that "mvn" was an alias to a repository inside my local network and wouldn't work anywhere else.  {facepalm}

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks

Comment: Tried this solution with dind and shared home volume. Got output files created in agent container by root user. Jenkins user in Jenkins container then can't delete them. Still struggling with this issue, but Tom's solution makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

To use current maven images in a jenkins pipeline as a non root user, try the following docker volume mapping and maven environment configuration:

```
args '-v $HOME/.m2:/var/maven/.m2:z -e MAVEN_CONFIG=/var/maven/.m2 -e MAVEN_OPTS="-Duser.home=/var/maven"'
```

https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven#running-as-non-root

Comment: You can add the ` quotation mark before and after your code to format your code like `this`.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Just faced another minor issue. I use two containers setup from [official guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/) (jenkins+dind). `docker run` (at least in this case) is executed by root. Thus, if `$HOME/.m2` didn't exist before, it's created owned by root. You need ensure it exists and owned by `jenkins` user before using pipeline.